# Convert postgres array to jsonb

Tags: postgresql

How we can convert postgres array :- `ARRAY['{"id": "1"}', '{"id": "2"}']` to JSONB `'[{"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}]'`

Comment: Did you try using one of the functions here? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html

Comment: yes, I tried but no function seems to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have an array of JSON values, and want to turn that into a single JSONB value which is an array.

You can unnest your array, then cast the elements to JSONB and aggregate that back using `jsonb_agg()`:

```
select jsonb_agg(j::jsonb)
from unnest(ARRAY['{"id": "1"}', '{"id": "2"}']) as x(j);
```

Comment: thanks a ton. works like a charm

Answer (score 14):

The array_to_json function with a cast to jsonb accomplishes this.

Example: `select array_to_json(ARRAY['{"id": "1"}', '{"id": "2"}'])::jsonb;`

Comment: This is by far the better way to do this!

Comment: This is strange. Do you know why there is no `array_to_jsonb` function?