# Convert Integer Array to JSON Array

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, cast

I'm not sure how I should go about converting `int[]` to `json[]`, here's what I've tried so far:

```
db=# alter table product alter column images type json[] using images::json[];
ERROR:  cannot cast type integer[] to json[]
LINE 1: ...roduct alter column images type json[] using images::json[];
                                                              ^
-- I thought converting to text[] first would help
db=# alter table product alter column images type text[] using images::text[];
ALTER TABLE

db=# alter table product alter column images type json[] using images::json[];
ERROR:  could not identify a comparison function for type json

-- Going back to int[]
db=# alter table product alter column images type int[] using images::integer[];
ALTER TABLE
```

```
-- Trying some json functions to help conversion
db=# alter table product alter column images type json[] using array_agg(array_to_json(images))::json[];
ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in transform expressions
LINE 1: ...ble product alter column images type json[] using array_agg(...

-- I thought a subquery would prevent the above error
db=# ALTER TABLE product
ALTER COLUMN images TYPE json[]
USING (
  SELECT array_agg(array_to_json(images))::json[]
  FROM product
);
ERROR:  cannot use subquery in transform expression
LINE 3: USING (
              ^
```

I've read these links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686187/how-to-convert-json-array-into-postgres-int-array-in-postgres-9-3

[How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array)

[Convert postgres array to jsonb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/234318/convert-postgres-array-to-jsonb)

Comment: `jsonb[]` or  `json[]` almost never makes sense. You should convert it into a `jsonb` column that contains a JSON array

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think you're right, I may just have to add an extra key `{"images": the_array}`. I have come across many errors using even `int[]` or `text[]` when inserting from the Peewee ORM. Might just forget that array fields exist at all 

Comment: Why would you need an additional key? If you have an int array now (`'{1,2,3}'`) , you'll have a JSON array afterwards `[1, 2, 3]`. But avoiding array completely is not a bad strategy.